# Why is the necessary amount of rep for comments everywhere set to 50

Tags: discussion, comments

I was just wondering why we need 50 rep to be able to comment everywhere. I mean it does cause problems. If I have an intuition on how to answer a problem or I want to ask for more info on the user's problem all I can do is type in a new answer which will then be downvoted by the community because well it's not an answer... So for newbies on the site it's pretty hard to reach 50rep ...

Just wanted some thoughts on that :).

NB: I'm not criticizing, just presenting my thoughts on the matter :). Would love to hear yours :).

EDIT: the answer provided in similar other posts don't really suit what I'm asking. All I am stating is that a complete a detailed answers give you rep, but a vague answer most of the time gets you downvotes. Yet, to provide a complete answer you do need sometimes to ask questions to the poster

Comment: Thoughts: this has been asked thousands of times. Also "for newbies on the site it's pretty hard to reach 50 rep" is simply false. You need 5 upvotes to answers (alternatively two upvotes, two accepts), or 10 upvotes to questions, or just 25 approved suggested edits. In your case, you need just _one_ answer upvote or one accept. If that's "pretty hard" then you're doing it wrong.

Comment: 50 rep isn't that hard... 1 or 2 decent answers should get you enough.

Comment: What do you think is a better threshold to prevent overwhelming comment-spam? Anyway, 50 aren't actually hard to get. Also, I'm missing any thought but "rep is hard, 50 too hard, let's lower it", which is a meme by now.

Comment: What I'm saying is that It's difficult to provide a complete answer without being able to comment on the questions to ask for some more specific details. I'm not saying it's tough as hell to get 50, what I am saying is that to actually provide a complete answer it is quite useful to be able to comment on the question first

Comment: Owning my upvote - I think this is a reasonable question which isn't addressed by the help. Not that the limit is wrong, just that it's reasonable to want to understand why it's there. I found it frustrating myself.

Comment: @redbirdo You saved my 2 minutes `rendering` != `wondering` :)

Comment: Yeah sorry about that, my phone autocorrect ^^". @redbirdo yes I am not against the limit at all as you state I just want to understand the state of mind behind the "you can answer but you cannot ask for more details to provide a more complete answer"

Comment: Re "It's difficult to provide a complete answer without being able to comment": If you cannot reasonably answer a question without additional information, the correct thing to do would be _flagging the question for closure_. There are multiple close reasons related to missing information and unclear questions; please use them. And of course, once you do have enough rep to comment and if you feel like spoon-feeding people, you can post a specific comment explaining what OP should add to their question.

Comment: Like do we seriously need to close a question because OP didn't think that a detail would matter? I am quite puzzled to read that. IMHO, this is a bit harsh for the OP

Comment: @Lonni Yes we do want to close questions which aren't clear enough to answer. There's no point in having unanswerable questions hanging around the system. They can always be reopened if the OP gets around to providing the necessary information.

Comment: @LonniBesançon: And having dozens of people waste their time trying to answer would be better, which by-the-way inundates him with useless posts? You know getting a post, when it deserves it, re-opened is fast and painless?

Comment: I just think that there is some middle ground between an unanswerable question and a question that just lacks a little detail to get a full answer... I may be wrong as I'm still new but it just seems wrong to flag and close a question that is both interesting and not unanswerable

Comment: Yes, the middle ground is called "on hold" and "reopen queue". "Flagging to close" is not the same as "reporting as spam" or something in forums.

Comment: Except that you cannot flag as on hold or whatever if you don't have 50 rep ...

Comment: @Lonni It's the same thing. When closing, a question is first "held" to give the OP a chance to improve it.

Comment: Donn't know why nobody added it. When you have some good rep on some stackoverflow sites, you automatically get **100** rep on any new site. So only when you're new to stackoverflow itself does this problem arise.

Comment: It never made any sense to me that you (1) are allowed to post answers, (2) are not allowed to post comments and (3) are left with no alternative way for asking additional information required to properly answer a question, since posting comments as answers is a big no-no on this site. Yes, it does make new users feel very unwelcome! Yes, it does chase away many of them! Yes, that totally sucks!! I'm afraid that's just something you have to live with, though. This issue has been pointed out at nauseam, and no one with the power to do so seems to want to fix it... :-(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SO is a technocracy. The more you prove your technical prowess the more reputation you get in the system and thereby gain more privileges. Questions and answers are subject to peer reviews (votes), while comments are not. If you write nonsense, spam or other unwanted content in an answer or question, you can be "voted out" of the system by your peers. That does not apply to comments which are purposefully "neutral territory", however that also means they can be abused more easily.

SO wants you to prove a bare minimum of worth to participate in the system, and you can do that by posting technically correct answers or questions. Yes, you may have to pick and choose a few specific questions to answer initially without the ability to comment, but seeing that SO is getting new questions literally every second it shouldn't be too hard to find one you can answer. Once you cross the initial threshold by showing that you know what you're talking about, you can interact with others more freely.

Comment: Ok I do get it, but still I feel sometimes frustrated when I see people commenting and asking the exact question I wanted to ask 2 or 3 minutes before and then I see the answer that I thought of in the first place.

Comment: I can sympathise with that, and that probably means you're "worthy" of SO if you often "see" the right answer from the outset. You just have to prove that worth to the system while you're still in "training mode", so just go along with it for the time being. Shouldn't be too hard to get there, really.

Comment: Pretty sure you can flag comments...

Comment: Sure I'll do :). I just thought it would be cool to exchange a little on that matter with people who could feel the same as I do or completely differently. Apparently, judging from the comments above I do not agree with some members of the community

Comment: @user Yes you can, but that's more of an exception and requires human (moderator) intervention for most flag types. Voting on other posts is just part of the regular workflow.

Comment: @User112638726: There are tools to track late answer, and answer bumps the question to the front page, so it gets extra view from people. However, there is no interface to track incoming comments. That's the reason for all these restrictions.